# Sleep function in Windows, using C

Tags: c, windows, sleep

I need to sleep my program in Windows. What header file has the sleep function?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use:

```
#include <windows.h>

Sleep(sometime_in_millisecs); // Note uppercase S
```

And here's a small example that compiles with [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) and does what it says on the tin:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf( "starting to sleep...\n" );
    Sleep(3000); // Sleep three seconds
    printf("sleep ended\n");
}
```

Comment: "viewed 42374 times" - so obviously many people out there also had this question (and how should I know to prefix "msdn" for my google search when I was mainly doing some Linux/POSIX programming for now?)

Answer (score 8):

`SleepEx` function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686307.aspx) is the best choise if your program directly or indirectly creates windows (for example use some COM objects). In the simples cases you can also use `Sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx): Header: Winbase.h (include Windows.h)

Comment: When I include windows.h my compiler gives "error: parameter name omitted" and " error: expected expression before ',' token"

Comment: @Snigger Post a short example that demonstrates this, and tell us what compiler you are using.

Comment: #include <windows.h>
    void writeData(result * res ,char *OUT){
    }
    int main(){
     return 1; 
    }  

gives " error: expected ')' before '*' token" and I'm using GCC (mingw)

Comment: @Snigger Your program does not declare the type "result"  - nothing to do with windows or Sleep. and it does not give the error messages you said it did (it gives different ones).

Comment: it does! Not in the code above but in the main program it does.

Comment: @Snigger The code in your comment IS the main program. There is no point in posting code that does not illustrate what you are asking about.

Comment: No I mean I forgot to write the definition of that types in code above but in the other code that gives error those types are defined.

Comment: @Snigger What happens when you compile the code I posted in my answer?

Comment: This is NOT discussion/comments on my answer.  This is an entirely tangential discussion that belongs in its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following function at the start of your code, whenever you want to busy wait.  This is distinct from sleep, because the process will be utilizing 100% cpu while this function is running.

```
void sleep(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock())
        ;
}
```

Note that the name `sleep` for this function is misleading, since the CPU will not be sleeping at all.

Comment: 1. This does not answer the poster's questions
2. This is just wrong because it is still a busy loop (with or without a 'for' loop).

Comment: up vote. I was searching for some sleep function in windows C, except Sleep(). This is working fine. thanks.

Comment: This is not sleep, this is "keep busy in a tight loop", and put extra burden on CPU anyway. Sleep releases the CPU to do other things.

Comment: up vote too. Althogh it keeps CPU busy but this is much more accurate than `Sleep()`.