# Undefined reference to sleep() in Windows using glibc

Tags: c, windows, sleep

I made a simple snippet of code to record what the user input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  char letter;
  printf("Enter in a character:");
  scanf("%c", &letter);
  sleep(2);
  printf("Letter was: %c", letter);
  return 0;
}
```

In this code, it's supposed to sleep for 2 seconds on line 8.

Unfortunately, sleep is an undefined reference, even though I have the correct [library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html).

Is there any way to fix this problem in **Windows Vista**?

Comment: You are only showing that you are including the correct **header**, not necessarily linking against the right **library**. What is the command line you are using to compile and link?

Comment: Well, a simple `gcc a.c` is working perfectly with your code in my Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you mean Sleep() or sleep()? They aren't the same. What OS are you running on?

Comment: It works by using 'gcc', which OS and compiler do you use?

Comment: Since the code uses `<unicode.h>` the OS should be either a fully POSIX compliant one, or a virtual environment like MinGW or Cygwin. All those should should, by default, link with a standard library that should contain the `sleep` function.

Comment: @zeldarulez, to help us help you, you need to edit your question to include the complete error message. And not only the one regarding `sleep` but the complete output without modifications. The only "error" I can see in your code is that it's missing a `return` statement in the `main` function.

Comment: @Joachim: `return` statement shouldn't prevent compilation and linking. @OP post the complete compilation output.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You mean '<unistd.h>', not '<unicode.h>'. And MinGW, which the OP is using, does not provide a POSIX environment. It provides <unistd.h> but does not provide the supporting library; thus the OP's problem.

Comment: @JimBalter Ah yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 5):

sleep() is a POSIX function, but you are using MinGW, which does not provide POSIX support. To quote http://lists-archives.com/mingw-users/01723-including-library-for-unistd-h-header.html

> Remember that mingw does not provide any more Unix APIs than what the
>   Microsoft C runtime provides. (Well, actually it does, but only a bit
>   more, no "difficult" things.) The Microsoft C runtime provides Unixish
>   functions like open(), read(), close(), but not functions like
>   getuid(), getegid(), getppid().

Nor sleep(). If you want a POSIX environment, you need Cygwin or some other POSIX support on Windows; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX_for_Windows

If you only need what MinGW gives you + sleep(), you can use the Windows Sleep() function (note that it is capitalized), which takes an argument in milliseconds and requires that you include Windows.h (rather than unistd.h); see [sleep function in Windows, using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379139/sleep-function-in-windows-using-c)

Answer (score 2):

If a program has to sleep for 2 seconds you have enter 2000 inside sleep function..

Sleep(unsigned int) :- unsigned int is the number of milliseconds ( 1 second= 1000milliseconds)

Please give "s" as captial letter in Sleep(5000);

and include the header file Windows.h

Answer (score 1):

If it is an undefined reference, that means the linker is not linking the library containing *sleep* to your code.

You may have included *unistd.h* (which gives you appropriate function prototypes), but you must also link to the library containing the implementation of *sleep*.

Show how you are compiling and linking the program.

Comment: I use MinGW with version 4.6.2. In addition, I use code::blocks to compile my code

Comment: @zeldarulez: It's OK not to accept an answer if you don't get a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following function at the starting of your code, whenever you want to for the execution to pause without putting extra burden on CPU (in case of for loop)

```
void sleep(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a proper answer, you should be trying to get sleep to work, instead of doing a workaround.
This solution could be dangerous... besides, a loop, even without extra code, will put extra burden on CPU