# How do I delay a function in C?

Tags: c

I can't find a viable guide so I am asking how do I delay a function in C, in other words, how do I make a program wait a certain number of seconds before continuing to execute other functions?

For example:

```
printf("First Function.\n");

//program waits a certain number of seconds before executing next command

printf("Second function executed after certain amount of seconds");
```

I want to know, what is the command I use to make this happen?

```
delay();
```

for me doesn't work by the way.

I must add, `sleep()` doesn't work either.

Comment: You want `sleep()`

Comment: `sleep` on Unix, `Sleep` on Windows.

Comment: I suggest you google the question title.

Comment: There is no such capability in  standard C.    Solutions are specific to operating systems (or families of operating systems).  For example, `sleep()` under unix, `Sleep()` under windows.   You'll need to read the documentation for your target system and associated APIs.

Comment: "*`sleep()` doesn't work either.*" does not work in which sense? Please be more specific! On which platform are you experiencing these issues?

Comment: This question is related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14812233/694576 if not a duplicate to it.

Comment: @alk: Despite your 'not a duplicate' comment, I think it is covering exactly the same territory, and so I've made it a duplicate.  Whole-second vs sub-second sleeping is still sleeping.

Answer (score 7):

[`sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html) is what you’re looking for.

```
printf("First Function.\n");

sleep(20);  // Replace 20 with the "certain amount"

printf("Second function executed after certain amount of seconds")
```

Comment: The latest documentation is here; http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sleep() or select to add delay.

Comment: I am curious why `sleep()` wouldn't be thread-safe.

Comment: I edited my answer, I dont know why but I am just used to call select for delays in threads, documentation for sleep clearly says only calling thread sleeps

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of `pselect()`, which has nothing with thread-safety to do, but is async-signal safe.

Answer (score 1):

The [`sleep()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) function is POSIX. There is also the POSIX function [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) if more precision is needed.

There is the [`thrd_sleep()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26.5.7) function in C11 (from `threads.h`), but AFAIK this function is still not supported by glibc.

A simple sleep function could be implemented portably using the functions from `time.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void my_sleep(unsigned);
void delay_print(char *);

int main(void)
{
    delay_print("What is taking so long?");
    delay_print("Glad that's over!");
}

void my_sleep(unsigned duration)
{
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    double end = duration;
    time_t now;
    do {
        now = time(NULL);
    } while (difftime(now, start) < end);
}

void delay_print(char *msg)
{
    my_sleep(5);
    puts(msg);
}
```

Comment: this sucks all the available CPU cycles due to the 'polling', so probably not the best approach.

Comment: @user3629249-- I did write "simple sleep function," and I think that it was implicit in my answer that this could be used in the _absence_ of any appropriate library functions. I think that most OS will detect the load and make adjustments. I am not sure that there is a portable way to do this and avoid CPU overhead, but I would be happy to see an alternative :)

Comment: Conflictingly. I have minGW on windows 11 and eclipse findng `Sleep(10);` on `synchapi.h` and `sleep(10);` on `unistd.h`, why?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd -- I don't understand "_conflictingly_". `synchapi.h` is a Windows-only header which declares a `Sleep` function; `unistd.h` is the Posix header that declares `sleep`. You can have both on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use:

```
sleep(unsigned int seconds);   //   from the unistid.h
Sleep(int milliseconds);       //   from the Windows.h
```

Comment: POSIX's `sleep()` takes an `unsigned int`.