# What is the most efficient way to "sleep" for an arbitrary amount of time in c?

Tags: c

Is there a function that just sleeps. The amount of time is not an issue.
What method should be used so that the computer performance is not disturbed?

Comment: Whatever your OS supplies.

Comment: Also, the amount of time is usually an issue since the granularity on OS sleep() style calls is in the order of ms.  Shorter sleeps are awkward for a general-purpose OS, whereas much longer 'sleeps', ie. in the order of days, are better provided by an out-of-process OS scheduler, eg. like cron or Windows Scheduler.

Comment: There are many previous questions, [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812233/sleeping-for-milliseconds-on-windows-linux-solaris-hpux-ibm-aix-vxworks-wi)

Comment: How do you propose to judge whether or not your chosen method of doing nothing is "efficient"?

Answer (score 2):

Unix variants generally provide `sleep(seconds)` and `usleep(microseconds)`. `usleep()` has been deprecated in favor of the POSIX `nanosleep()`. Windows provides `Sleep( sometime_in_millisecs )`;

Windows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf( "starting to sleep...\n" );
    Sleep( 3000 );   // sleep three seconds
    printf( "sleep ended\n" );
}
```

Linux (Unix):

```
#include <unistd.h>

//unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

int main() {
    sleep( 3 ); // sleep 3 seconds
    usleep( 3000000 ); // sleep 3 seconds more
    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Note that `usleep` is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are using Linux platform, there is a standard C function that can sleep for microseconds.

```
#include <unistd.h>
unsigned int usec;
...
usleep(usec);
```

When Sleep is called, the program comes out from running state and re-enters to ready state when sleep time gets over, so no impact on CPU time. Other processes/threads may take advantage of CPU by then.
If `usleep` is not available on the Unix variant you use, alternately, you may use `sleep` is the granularity is in seconds,

```
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
```

Comment: `usleep` is not a "standard C function".

Comment: `usleep()` is an obsolete POSIX function; still available in POSIX are [`sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html), and [`nanosleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html). There is also [`thrd_sleep`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26.5.7) from `threads.h`; standard in C11, but still unsupported in glibc.