# Simple Python function that holds the GIL

Tags: python, python-multithreading, gil

I would like to test how my application responds to functions that hold the GIL.  Is there a convenient function that holds the GIL for a predictable (or even a significant) amount of time?

My ideal function would be something that operated like `time.sleep` except that, unlike sleep, it would hold the GIL

Comment: Functions don't hold the GIL (and can't). The Python interpreter loop does. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a **C** callable that doesn't explicitly tell the interpreter to release the GIL while it runs?

Comment: I think I need this because I want to test how my distributed system performs when asked to run functions that cause the interpreter loop to hold the GIL for long periods of time: http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: That package is built in Pure Python and uses multiprocessing. There is no need to worry about the GIL there, *it doesn't apply there*.

Comment: At any rate, there are *no* Pure Python functions that hold the GIL for long periods of time, because they can't hold the GIL. The GIL is a C-level entity, that C extensions can release to let the interpreter thread execute some more Python bytecode.

Comment: There are functions, accessible from Python, that do hold the GIL.  These functions may themselves call C code that does not release the GIL.

Comment: No, they *don't hold the GIL*. They do not signal that the lock can be released, that's a *big difference*. And again, **you don't need to worry about the GIL**, because you are not using threading.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting that from.  I do use theads for computation, I do need to worry about the GIL, and for my purposes there isn't a huge difference.  If someone calls a function, say `pandas.DataFrame.merge`, which currently causes the GIL to be held for a long time, then my I/O will cease for a while.  I'm getting bad behavior because of this and I'd like to test it.

Comment: I'm curious if there was ever any further developments here. Specifically - I'm confused as to how a `pandas.DataFrame.merge` would itself block the GIL. In the situation of needing consistent communication with a worker in a distributed situation, should that opportunity be provided every n ticks?
Given that Numpy operations occur outside the GIL - what specific aspect would be blocking/preventing the worker's communication? Unless the Numpy step constitutes a "long tick" (interpreter instruction) that itself creates a timeout (?).

Answer (score 4):

A simple, but hacky, way to hold the GIL is to use the `re` module with a known-to-be-slow match:

```
import re
re.match(r'(a?){30}a{30}', 'a'*30)
```

On my machine, this holds the GIL for 48 seconds with Python 2.7.14 (and takes almost as long on 3.6.3). However, this relies on implementation details, and may stop working if the `re` module gets improvements.

A more direct approach would be to write a c module that just sleeps. Python C extensions don't automatically release the GIL (unlike, say, ctypes). Follow the hellomodule example [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C), and replace the `printf()` with a call to `sleep()` (or [the Windows equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379146/7581)). Once you build the module, you'll have a GIL holding function you can use anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a C library's sleep function in "PyDLL" mode.

```
# Use libc in ctypes "PyDLL" mode, which prevents CPython from
# releasing the GIL during procedure calls.
_libc_name = ctypes.util.find_library("c")
if _libc_name is None:
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot find libc")
libc_py = ctypes.PyDLL(_libc_name)
...
libc_py.usleep(...)
```

(See https://gist.github.com/jonashaag/d455671003205120a864d3aa69536661 for details on how to pickle the reference, for example if using in a distributed computing environment.)

Comment: libc functions can be accessed without a name using `libc_py = ctypes.PyDLL(None)` so you can skip the lookup step