# Webots pause simulation

Tags: c, events, pause, webots

I am building a little maze solver project using Webots. I am writing my controller in C programming language. I am using Windows OS.

Can someone let me know if there is a way to pause the simulation when a certain event happens?

Something like :

```
if(event){
    pause(10 seconds);
    continue();
}
```

This is part of the code I wrote (where I want to introduce the pause). `while(wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP) != -1)` is in a infinite while loop.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  //… initialization code for Webots API, not important

  // feedback loop: step simulation until an exit event is received
  while (wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP) != -1) {

    // read sensors outputs
    for (i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
      ps_values[i] = wb_distance_sensor_get_value(ps[i]);
    }

    //program
    goForward();
    if (forwardWall()==1) {
      //pause needed here 
      turnLeft(1);
    }
    else if(rightWall()==0){
      Uturn();
    }   
 } 
  // cleanup the Webots API
  wb_robot_cleanup();
  return 0; //EXIT_SUCCESS
}
```

EDIT : The solution was using the `Sleep()` function. It did not work at first because I was not importing the `<windows.h>` library.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  In Linux [sleep()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) can be used.  In Windows [Sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379139/sleep-function-in-windows-using-c) can be used.  I am not sure what `continue();` is for in your code example.

Comment: Note that Linux sleep is in seconds, Windows sleep is in milliseconds.

Comment: @ryyker I am using Windows. I tried using Sleep(1000), but I got a warning, and it doesn't pause at all. Do I need to import this function from a library ?

Comment: @ryyker `warning: implicit declaration of function 'Sleep'; did you mean '_sleep'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: What was the warning?  Did you look at the link I left?  It includes several examples, including  header file to use.  By the way, when asking a question like this it would just be good to include the environment information from the start, i.e. OS, Development tools, etc.  Its also generally best to include a [mcve].  Without seeing your code, there is no way to see if there is some other problem, such as compile time warnings, or algorithm issues.

Comment: That warning is telling you that the function you are calling has not been not been declared. Header files (such as #include <windows.h> are where function declarations are made. Libraries (or source code) are where they are defined. In this case Sleep() will be in a library. What environment are you using to compile your code?  (see simple example below.)

Comment: In case you are interested, there is an installer for the _[Code::Blocks IDE that bundles GCC](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26#windows)_ here.

Comment: @ryyker I did not notice the links you left (I'm new). I also updated my post to include the code I'm working with.

Comment: @ryyker I tried using the Sleep() function and included the required library. I got no more error, but it still doesn't work. I put a pause of 10 seconds at the beginning of the program, but as soon as I click start, my robot starts moving. Might be in conflict with Webots ?

Comment: It depends on where it is called.  What calls are being made in `main()` (you do not include that part of your code in the post.), and in what sequence?  (Try putting the `Sleep(10000);` function as the very first function call in the `main()` function, before any `webot` calls are made.  That will test whether it is working )

Comment: @ryyker It works now. I was making a stupid mistake. Thank you for your time ! I updated my now working code.

Comment: I am glad to know you were able find the issue.  However replacing your problem code with working code is not a good idea as it removes the reason for the post in the first place to future readers :).  It would be better  to add an edit section at the bottom of your post with a brief description of what you have done, eg:  `EDIT: -Here is what was done to fix the problem: (add code and/or description below)`    (You can add your fix in an edit, but it is not necessary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I am using Windows. I tried using Sleep(1000), but I got a warning...*

This small example will compile and run using *[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)*:

```
#include <windows.h> //Sleep()
#include <stdio.h> //printf()

int main(void) 
{
    Sleep(10000); // 10 seconds
    printf("process continuing...\n");

    return 0;
}
```