# How can I make each character in a string sequentially appear in the console like in a game? (Lua)

Tags: text, lua, console

I'm trying to write a function in Lua, which essentially is supposed to write out each character sequentially to the console after given a piece of text as the input parameter each time the function is called. So for example, if I call the function and put "Hello World" as the parameter, I want the function to sequentially print out each character to the console one at a time (with a given amount of time between each character, therefore creating a kind of "flow" of letters). The function that I've been working on technically does what I want it to, however it doesn't display *any* text at all until the loop is completely done iterating over each character in the string. So if I wanted to display "hello" to console with one second between each character being printed, it would take roughly 5-6 seconds before any text at all would appear (and when it did, it would be the full string). I've tried re-organizing the function in any way I can think of, but I can't think of any other way to sequentially output each character without a loop. Is this just a Lua problem? I've seen this same general question but for C#, and it appears they both work in the same way ([How to make text be "typed out" in console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337336/how-to-make-text-be-typed-out-in-console-application)). Also, for the record, I'm coding in an online IDE called "repl.it" and I haven't abandoned the idea that that might be a problem. Thanks in advance.

```
--[[ Delay function --]]
function wait(seconds)
    local start = os.time()
    repeat until os.time() > start + seconds
end


--[[ Function for "saying" things --]]
function say(string)
  speakchar = {}
  speakindex = 1;
  for c in (string):gmatch"." do
    table.insert(speakchar, c);
    io.write(speakchar[speakindex])
    wait(1);
    speakindex = speakindex + 1;
  end
  print("");
end
```

Comment: Add `io.flush()` after `io.write`.

Comment: No need to store the chars in a table btw. Just `io.write(c)`will do.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much! It totally worked! I'll get rid of that table as well, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I strongly suggest to build your own wait() with C - If you are on linux you can do it by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112973/embedded-lua-5-4-2-link-errors/67115641#67115641 - That dont bring your CPU fans to noisy ;-) - And you can easy make waits lower than one second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush the output buffer. Here is the simplified code:

```
function say(string)
  for c in (string):gmatch"." do
    io.write(c):flush()
    wait(1);
  end
  io.write("\n")
end
```